# How to download files from URLs saved inside a text file which require a conda package?

Tags: python, http, url, download

I have saved a set of URLs of downloadable data files. These set of URLs require a specific package from conda/python to download. The usual format of conda/python command line to download a single file is as below;

```
python -m client_name --client http://url_to_data
```

But I need to automate the process for 100s of files (URLs saved in a single file). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

*How can I do this?*
When you are using `-m` name of module follows, so for

```
python -m client_name --client http://url_to_data
```

you should take a look at `client_name` module, as there is chance it does provide interface to be used in python scripts. If this is not case you might use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) for each of 100 of said files (if you use python 3.5 or newer) xor [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) (if you use older python)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subprocess.run` to run a command prompt / terminal command in python. The code below shows you how to use the command, so just put the `run` function inside of a loop that iterates over different URLs and it should run your command for each of them.

```
from subprocess import run

command = "python -m client_name --client http://url_to_data"
run(command, shell=True)
```